# Angularjs update directive view - Error: ngRepeat:dupes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**index.html**:

```
<body ng-app="homeApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
   <xi-folder-nav></xi-folder-nav>
   <button class="btn btn-default " type="button" xi-search>Search</button>
</body>
```

**nav.html**:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb" >
<li ng-repeat="n in folderNav" ng-class="{'active' : $last}">
    <a href="#" ng-hide="$last">{{ n }}</a>
    <span ng-show="$last">{{ n }}</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

**service.js**:

```
angular
    .module('homeApp')
    .service('dataService', dataService);

dataService.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
function dataService($rootScope) {
    var service = {
        folderNav: ['root'],

        addFolderNav: function(nav){
            service.folderNav.push( nav );
            $rootScope.$broadcast( 'folderNav.update' );
        },
    };

    return service;
}
```

**controller.js**:

```
angular
    .module('homeApp')
    .controller('homeCtrl',homeCtrl);

homeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','dataService'];
function homeCtrl($scope,dataService) {
    $scope.$on( 'folderNav.update', function( event ) {
        $scope.folderNav = dataService.folderNav;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
    $scope.folderNav = dataService.folderNav;
```

**directive.js**:

```
angular
    .module('homeApp')
    .directive('xiFolderNav', xiFolderNav);
    .directive('xiSearch', xiSearch);

xiFolderNav.$inject = ['dataService'];
function xiFolderNav(dataService) {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/app/home/nav.html',
    };
}

xiSearch.$inject = ['dataService'];
function xiSearch(dataService) {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('click', function(){
            dataService.addFolderNav('gg');
        });

    }
}
```

I want to add some data to `nav.html` and update the view. But when I click button the second time, it shows some errors.

I have already added the `$scope.$apply()` to the controller like most people do, but it does not work well!

**Error**:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=n%20in%20folderNav&p1=string%3Agg&p2=gg
```

Comment: For information on the error, see [AngularJS Error Reference - ngRepeat: dupes](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=n%20in%20folderNav&p1=string%3Agg&p2=gg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by `Duplicate key in Repeater` of `ng-repeat`. Refer [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=n%20in%20folderNav&p1=string:gg&p2=gg).

You can add `track by $index` to avoid this error or check for duplicates before push to Repeater.

Comment: One more question, What can I do if I don't use the $apply to capture the change in the directive? And what the most people do in this case?

Comment: @hiroxi I think you are trying to share data between controller and directive. For shared service, you can refer this plunker and keep in mind that `broadcast` is the last option to achieve this.http://plnkr.co/edit/3xVseS8wN8Y5yJ9b2KZl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are adding duplicate value in the array, over which you are iterating with `ng-repeat`.

The error text explains it all (on the link),

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to
>   specify unique keys. Repeater: n in folderNav, Duplicate key:
>   string:gg, Duplicate value: gg

As on `click` you are adding `'gg'` to the array, so there is a chance of multiple entries of the same element.

If that is intentional and you want to have multiple entries and make `ng-repeat` work, you have to explicitly mention the unique key, to `ng-repeat`.

You can specify unique key as,

```
<ol class="breadcrumb" >
<li ng-repeat="n in folderNav track by $index" ng-class="{'active' : $last}">
    <a href="#" ng-hide="$last">{{ n }}</a>
    <span ng-show="$last">{{ n }}</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

In above code, `$index` is unique for each element in array, it is the index number of element in the array.